# MomentJS date string adds one day

Tags: date, momentjs

I don't understand why this date is saved as +1 day:

```
startdate = "2017-11-29T23:59:59.999Z";
var new_date = moment(startdate).format('DD/MM/YYYY'); // --> gives 30/11/2017
```

But if I do:

```
startdate = "2017-11-29";
var new_date = moment(startdate).format('DD/MM/YYYY'); // --> gives the correct date 29/11/2017
```

Any ideas?

Here is a jsfiddle showing this: http://jsfiddle.net/jbgUt/416/

Thanks!

Comment: Because `2017-11-29T23:59:59.999Z` is an UTC date (note the `Z` at the end) while moment by default uses local time. What is your environment's UTC offset / timezone?

Comment: Ok thanks that was the problem. But what do you mean by environment's offset?

Comment: I mean which is the timezone of environment where your code is executed? The output depends on the UTC offset, you will get 29/11/2017 in your first sample if you set UTC offset to 0, see [`utcOffset`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/) and [timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) to get further info.

Comment: Ha ok :) UTC timezone.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> If a time part is included, an offset from UTC can also be included as +-HH:mm, +-HHmm, +-HH or Z.

Add `utc()` to avoid it.

```
moment(startdate).utc().format('DD-MM-YYYY')
```

or

```
moment.utc(startdate).format('DD-MM-YYYY')
```

> If you want to parse or display a moment in UTC, you can use moment.utc() instead of moment()

Comment: I'm glad I could help )

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party on this one, but I did just convert a few of our product's date-time objects to https://moment.github.io/luxon/

Takes out the need for the `.utc()` method above.